# What do ExplSyntaxOn and ExplSyntaxOff do?

Tags: latex3, expl3

Related to the question [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) for LaTeX2e, here related to LaTeX3

**What do `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` do?**

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The LaTeX3 coding language, `expl3`, uses `:` and `_` as 'letters' in function and variable names. This allows use of `expl3` code-level material in a document

```
\cs_new:Npn .... % fails: command \cs followed by characters '_', 'n', 'e', 'w', etc.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn .... % works here: command name \cs_new:Npn
```

The `\ExplSyntaxOn` command activates this, and also alters the treatment of spaces and line endings so these are ignored, meaning that

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \my_function:nn #1#2
  {
    % Code hre
  }
```

does not require `%` at the end of each line (compare to 'normal' LaTeX2e code). To allow inclusion of spaces in the output, `~` is made into a 'normal' space by `\ExplSyntaxOn`. Note that this change in the behaviour of spaces is not essential to access `expl3` names, but the two are closely tied together as the combination allows 'clearer' programming in `expl3`.

`\ExplSyntaxOff` reverses this, returning `:`, `_` and `~` to their values before `\ExplSyntaxOn` and making spaces 'important' again.

At a technical level, the idea of category codes in command names is exactly the same as in [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do), although the `\ExplSyntax...` switches do more.

---

A couple of points to note about the treatment of `~` within a code block. First, as `~` is a 'space' inside a code block, a `~` at the start of a line is ignored by TeX

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
~ \cs_new:Npn ....
```

is exactly the same as

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn ....
```

as the 'space' is ignored.

Secondly, while `~` is a 'space' inside a code block, `\␣` and `\~` are still distinct and have the LaTeX2e definitions.

---

There are a few more details to discuss for completeness. `\ExplSyntaxOn` also sets catcodes appropriately for other characters that implicitly are part of its syntax:

- TAB — ignored (just like spaces)
- `"` — an ‘other’ char, necessary for hexadecimal input such as `\int_eval:n { "F }` (= 15)
- `&` — alignment character for tabular material
- `^` — superscript char for `^^64` style notation
- `|` — an ‘other’ char, necessary for `expl3` boolean expressions

Answer (score 25):

I want to add some information about the combination of LaTeX2e kernel macros and expl3 functions. The command `\ExplSyntaxOn` doesn't change the catcode of the special token `@`. So combining of LaTeX2e kernel macros and expl3 functions you have to call `\makeatletter`, too:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_set:Npn \@maketitle…
```

Comment: Good point.  Of course, in the ultimate version of LaTeX3, there will be no such thing as `\@maketitle`, because `@` is not part of the expl3 syntax :)  For the moment, this is something to remember.

Comment: I usually do `\cs_set:cpn {@maketitle} ...`