# Use expl3 inside a LaTeX2e macro

Tags: expl3, latex3

I would like to redefine the \section macro in my document and I found that LaTeX3e was one of the easiest way to make integer operations inside it. But I get a "Missing $ inserted" error when I compile. A minimal example is the following :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \int_zero_new:N \g_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\fooinc{
    \ExplSyntaxOn
        \int_incr:N \g_int
    \ExplSyntaxOff
}

\begin{document}
    \fooinc
\end{document}
```

Why doesn't the above code work ?

Comment: The `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` markers should go *around* the definition, not inside it.

Comment: I thought it only made _ and : letters. If you turn your comment into a more detailed answer (why wouldn't it work), I will accept it.

Comment: Analogous with `\makeatletter` [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201348/21930).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [What do ExplSyntaxOn and ExplSyntaxOff do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108696/what-do-explsyntaxon-and-explsyntaxoff-do) and its sibling [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

When TeX reads a definition, it just stores the tokens it is given, *without* doing any assignment. In particular, `\ExplSyntaxOn` in your definition is not performed and so `\fooinc` is defined to expand to the following tokens (I use • as token separator, for better reading):

```
\ExplSyntaxOn•\int•_•i•n•c•r•:•N• •\g•_•i•n•t• •\ExplSyntaxOff
```

so the macro `\ExplSyntaxOn` will be executed too late.

The correct way is

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_zero_new:N \g_florian_whatever_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \fooinc
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_florian_whatever_int
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

You have declared your integer parameter as global, so it should always be managed with global assignments. And `\g_int` is a badly chosen name.

Instead of `\newcommand`, it's better to use `\cs_new_protected:Npn`, if not `\NewDocumentCommand` of `xparse` (probably even a better choice).

Comment: I would like to use large portions of text inside my macros, is there a way not to replace all the spaces with ~ ?

Comment: @Florian Not sure what you mean.

Comment: If I put \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff around my macro, then spaces inside it are ignored. But I would like to put a large portion of text with spaces inside it. Is there a way to write them normally (" " instead of "~") to ensure legebility ?

Comment: @Florian There are several ways. An example in a new question would be better.