# In expl3, how to use normal spaces instead of ~ in a portion of text?

Tags: expansion, expl3

In a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318544/use-expl3-inside-a-latex2e-macro/318547?noredirect=1), I learned that \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff should be put around a command because of the order in which expansion works in TeX.

Suppose now that I want to put things at the begining  where I want to use expl3 and to input a huge text as in :

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \bool_if:nT{\g_florian_whatever_bool} %\g_florian_whatever_bool being set with a key
  {
    blahblah %blahblah being a huge token list with many spaces
  }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

How can I still use normal spaces ' ' while writing blahblah ? I want to ensure legibility and ~ is not the best way.

Comment: Could you give more detailed example of the situation? It's not clear why would you need to input that many text on an internal function rather than on a `\NewDocumentCommand`, and also not clear why is “readability” that important. Usually you can write a text and then substitute in your editor the spaces for `~`, in case the input is a problem for you.

Comment: For example, I would like to use expl3 syntax inside a \AtBeginDocument (which leads to the same type of problems) to input text if a boolean key is set as true (I do not like \fi).

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand \fooinc { m } { #1 \ing_gincr:N \g_florian_whatever_int }` and then after exiting expl3-mode `\AtBeginDocument{\fooinc{the text that you want to add}}`?

Comment: I'll edit my question more because it is not yet explicit enough.

Comment: Why do you need spaces for testing a boolean? You should need spaces only for typesetting, i.e., stuff used *after* begin document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two examples that you could use

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_florian_whatever_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \setbegdoctext { m }
  { \tl_gset:Nn \g_florian_whatever_tl { #1 } }
\NewDocumentCommand \printifwhatever { }
  { \bool_if:NT \g_florian_whatever_bool { \tl_use:N \g_florian_whatever_tl } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\AtBeginDocument{\printifwhatever}
\setbegdoctext{the text you want to print at the beginning of the document}
```

or

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \printifwhatever { m } { \bool_if:NT \g_florian_whatever_bool { #1 } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\AtBeginDocument{\printifwhatever{the text you want to print at the beginning of the document}}
```