# Generating graphs with smooth edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Is there some way to produce these figures using TeX itself preferably using TikZ? If yes, then I would also like to add labels right next to the nodes rather than using a legend.

[image]

This is a screenshot from a paper I am reading and I would prefer using TeX to create them than using some external tools.

**EDIT**

I read the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz?answertab=votes#tab-top) but I would like to add the 'crosses' on the line instead of a gray colored line pointing to where the cross must exist. Moreover, I don't know how to change the crosses to the different symbols given in the diagram drawn above.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On the smooth plots there are a couple of questions on the site [Easy curves in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33607/106162) and [Curve through a sequence of points with Metapost and TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54771/106162).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `to` with the angles as parameter, at which the lines enter and leave nodes.

```
\draw (from-node) to[out=angle at from-node,in=angle at to-node] (to-node);
```

The angles are measured from the positive x-axis.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
  {dest/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=1mm,inner sep=0mm},
   start/.style={diamond,fill,draw,minimum width=1mm, minimum height=1mm,inner sep=0mm},
   terminal/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=1.5mm,inner sep=0mm,label={[label distance=-2.75mm]{\tiny+}}}
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[start,label={[right]:$s$}] (s) at (0,0) {};
  \node[dest,label={[left]:$d_1$}] (d1) at (-1,0.5) {};
  \node[dest,label={[right]:$d_2$}] (d2) at (0.3,0.6) {};
  \node[dest,label={[right]:$d_3$}] (d3) at (0,1.5) {};
  \node[dest,label=$d_4$] (d4) at (-1,2) {};
  \node[terminal,label={[left]:$t$}] (t) at (-0.9,1.3) {};
  \draw (s) to[out=170,in=-90] (d1);
  \draw (d1) to[out=70,in=-100] (d2);
  \draw (d2) to[out=100,in=-60] (d3);
  \draw (d3) to[out=120,in=30] (d4);
  \draw (d4) to[out=-110,in=100] (t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh yes that's it! Thanks for tolerating my OCD! :P

Comment: @BanachTarski First, I feel deeply honoured to be addressed by Tarski ;) Second, I've added node labels.

Comment: @gernot I bet you didn't know that his first name was Banach, though, eh? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

To get a more automated smooth connection with less of the manual labour you can use `\draw [smooth] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,0) (1,0) (1,1)};` where the key `tension=1.5` specifies the tightness to the straight line.  See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33610/106162) for some more details discussion of the functionality of this sort of command.

Using [`expl3`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) (I loaded [`xparse`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and used `\NewDocumentCommand` rather than `\newcommand` but that bit could be done with LaTeX2e) I've defined a new command which takes a set of coordinates separated by `;` (this could be any reasonable separator, I used `;` over `,` as coordinates naturally have the `(a,b)` description) as a single input.  The coordinates are then split up into a `seq` variable (`\l__banachtarski_coords_seq`) from which they are extracted for plotting.  As well as an optional argument which sets a value for `tension` of the plot.

To my knowledge [`TikZ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) does not offer `mark first`, `mark last`, and `mark middle` type commands in `\draw plot` options so I first plot a smooth line between all the points with `\draw plot [smooth, tension=1.5] coordinates { \seq_use:Nn \l__banachtarski_coords_seq { ~ } };` which produces the smooth line and then to place the marks I use a rather inefficient approach which places a mark at the first coordinate and a mark at the second using distinct marks, removing them from `\l__banachtarski_coords_seq` in the process

```
\seq_pop_left:NN \l__banachtarski_coords_seq \l__banachtarski_temp_tl
\draw plot [only~marks,mark=diamond*,mark~options={fill=black}] coordinates {
  \l__banachtarski_temp_tl
};

\seq_pop_right:NN \l__banachtarski_coords_seq \l__banachtarski_temp_tl
\draw plot [only~marks,mark=oplus*,mark~options={fill=gray}] coordinates {
  \l__banachtarski_temp_tl
};
```

and then plotting the remaining middle coordinates with a third mark

```
\draw plot [only~marks,mark=*,mark~options={fill=gray}] coordinates {
  \seq_use:Nn \l__banachtarski_coords_seq { ~ }
};
```

`only~marks` (which draws the marks but no connecting lines) has to be used rather than `only marks` as this is all happening inside [`\ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108696/106162) although it is probably only needed for plotting the final set of marks.

Thus (using the same coordinates as [gernot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341180/106162) which offers much finer control at more expense of effort)) one can generate
[image]
from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__banachtarski_coords_seq
\tl_new:N \l__banachtarski_temp_tl

\NewDocumentCommand \smoothgraph { O{1} m }
{
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l__banachtarski_coords_seq { ; } { #2 }

\draw plot [smooth, tension=#1] coordinates { \seq_use:Nn \l__banachtarski_coords_seq { ~ } };

\seq_pop_left:NN \l__banachtarski_coords_seq \l__banachtarski_temp_tl
\draw plot [only~marks,mark=diamond*,mark~options={fill=black}] coordinates { \l__banachtarski_temp_tl };

\seq_pop_right:NN \l__banachtarski_coords_seq \l__banachtarski_temp_tl
\draw plot [only~marks,mark=oplus*,mark~options={fill=gray}] coordinates { \l__banachtarski_temp_tl };

\draw plot [only~marks,mark=*,mark~options={fill=gray}] coordinates { \seq_use:Nn \l__banachtarski_coords_seq { ~ } };
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \smoothgraph{(0,0);(-1,0.5);(0.3,0.6);(0,1.5);(-1,2);(-0.9,1.3)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \smoothgraph[2]{(0,0);(-1,0.5);(0.3,0.6);(0,1.5);(-1,2);(-0.9,1.3)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```